# Detecting (not escaping) XSS vulnerabilities from an html or markdown string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, markdown, xss

I have a client side Markdown/HTML editor that submits markdown text to a server, and i need it to complain (ie. 400, Validation Error) if the Client's submitted text string has XSS vulnerabilities.

Given a string (either Markdown, or HTML converted from Markdown), how do i (unless there is already library for it) detect if there a string has XSS vulnerabilities?

Python libraries like `html-sanitizer` and `bleach` only remove and/or escape the offending XSS string sections.

Comment: You will always need to work with HTML. See [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/) for a good breakdown of the issues. As for raising an error, I expect you would need to modify the sanitizer to raise an error rather than make the modification of the HTML